# How to define API keys in restFul meteor?

Tags: api, rest, meteor, restful-authentication

I am new to rest api in meteorjs. I am trying to run the example explained in [The meteor chef](https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/writing-an-api/)  but getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: APIKeys is not defined
    at Object.API.authentication (api/config/api.js:4:19)
    at Object.API.connection (api/config/api.js:16:34)
    at Object.API.handleRequest (api/config/api.js:28:26)
    at [object Object].Router.route.where (api/pizza.js:9:9)
    at boundNext (packages/iron_middleware-stack/lib/middleware_stack.js:251:1)
    at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:110:1)
    at packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:123:1
    at [object Object].urlencodedParser (/Users/mac/.meteor/packages/iron_router/.1.0.12.13720an++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:84:40)
    at packages/iron_router/lib/router.js:277:1
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
```

The code is same as explained in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you didn't created `APIKeys` mongo collection as shown here: https://github.com/themeteorchef/writing-an-api/blob/master/code/collections/api-keys.js

Add this file to your project and then it'll work.

Here is explanation from post you linked:

> Next, we try to insert a new key for our user into the APIKeys collection. Wait a minute! Where did this come from?! This collection was setup beforehand, but let’s talk about why we have a separate collection to begin with. The reason we want to separate our API key storage from the more predictable location of our user’s profile (the writable portion of a user’s record in the Meteor.users() collection) is that by default, the profile object is writable.

So you just missed this part of tutorial where they created `APIKeys` collection.